# making table in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

and again maybe im been dumb or not seeing something I should but I am having a problem making a table in MySQL using a php script here is the code

```
$maketable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $scompany ( 
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  deskname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  lfloor VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,, 
  internet ENUM('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n', 
  pc ENUM('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',  
  monitor ENUM('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n', 
  extra TEXT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id))";

$tablequery = mysqli_query($db_x, $maketable);
```

but for some reason it wont work can you help please

Comment: there is syntax error in query, change your code to `$tablequery = mysqli_query($db_x, $maketable) or die(mysqli_error($db_x));` to see it

Comment: Yeah, let's just die. Because that's what we all do when things don't go as planned, right? We just die.

Comment: @Sherlock - it depends if your boss is the forgiving type or not!

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about Apple there for a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double comma in part

```
lfloor VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,,
```

What's the point of making separate table for each company? This is very bad idea and will give you many troubles.

Comment: the reason is I was thinking it would be easier for each company to edit their table they need to. but every says its a bad idea so I might rethink it

Answer (score 1):

There is a double komma in your Query at the end of this part:

```
 lfloor VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,,
```

Answer (score 0):

Be glad it doesn't work.

**You don't want to do this.**

Creating a table for every company, whatever the exact definition of *company* is in your application, is a Very Bad Thing to do. Try googling the term 'normalization' and see where that gets you.

Comment: normalization is of course great thing, but for performance reasons de-normalization can be considered as good option, also this is not an answer to problem

Comment: This clearly is no example of denormalizing because of performance issues. Also: this is the answer to the problem, but the problem is of a magnitude different from what the asker thinks it is.